# Exterior calculus with 0-forms on $r \theta$-plane

Tags: differential-forms

Solving problem from textbook, not homework.

Define the $r\theta$-plane on $\mathbb{R}^2$. Define 0-forms $f=r \cos \theta$ and $g = r \sin \theta \in \Omega^0(\mathbb{R}^2)$. Problem: *compute $df$, $dg$ and $df \wedge dg$ w.r.t. $dr$ and $d \theta$*.

My answer. For 0-forms the exterior derivative is defined as $$df = \sum \frac{\partial f_I}{\partial x_I} dx_I,$$
and the wedge product defined as $$\omega \wedge \tau = \sum_{I,J} (a_I b_J) dx_I \wedge dx_J.$$ Computing the exterior derivatives
\begin{align}
df &= \frac{\partial f}{\partial r}dr + \frac{\partial f}{\partial \theta}d\theta
&= \cos \theta dr - r \sin \theta d\theta
\end{align} 
and
\begin{align}
dg &= \frac{\partial g}{\partial r}dr + \frac{\partial g}{\partial \theta}d\theta
&= \sin \theta dr + r \cos \theta d\theta.
\end{align}

Computing the wedge product
\begin{align}
df \wedge dg &= (\cos \theta \sin \theta)dr \wedge d\theta - (r^2 \sin \theta \cos \theta)d\theta \wedge dr. 
\end{align}

Is this correct?

Comment: No, you cross multiplied the wrong terms together (e.g. $dr$ with $dr$ which shouldn't exist because $dr\wedge dr = 0$)

Comment: I reckon $(a\,dr+b\,d\theta)\wedge(c\,dr+d\,d\theta)=(ad-bc)dr\wedge d\theta$.

Comment: you are right, thanks. Should I attempt a self-answer and refer to your comments?